# how to find a word in a string and add the space angularjs or javascript or jquery?

Tags: angularjs

[Want to show the space between labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbiQm.png)

Want to add the space between words which is coming from backend as a one string so how to identify and display the words sepreatly by adding the space between them.

Comment: Is the server sending you the strings in camel casing?

Comment: angularjs or javascript or jquery lol.. the answer is python of course

Answer (score 0):

You can apply following angular filter to achieve the same. JSFiddle Reference -
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mqgptzbo/)

```
app.filter('separateWords', function() {
  return function(value) {
    return (!value) ? '' : value.split(/(?=[A-Z])+|(?=[0-9])+|(?=to)/).join(" ");
  }
});
```

E.g. `{{"RetunAddress1"|separateWords}}`

Comment: Thanks sumit, need small help again can you modify the value.match("expression") in a such way that it can detect small alphabet as well as numbers and add the space between them.

Comment: Sachin what is the exact requirement...based on your above comment it seems you want to add space between each character either capital/small/number is this correct? Or please specify one example with required output

Comment: "ReturnToAddress1"  should be "Return To Address 1"  and if their is a string like "MailtoAddress1" than it should be "Mail To Address 1"  Thanks

Comment: Sachin, based on your input data I modified my answer...Hope now this will work for you..

Comment: Sachin, Check and accept the answer if it works for you so that it will be available for reference to others. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sumit works perfectly for me!! u are the best programmer.